# How to use if condition in stored procedure after where

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have written this method for read the data of database.

```
string query = @"SELECT 
                    IDproduct, name_product, first_price, 
                    final_price, max_registered_price, 
                    date_record_shamsi, final_date_view_shamsi,
                    count_views, image_1, collection_1, city, model   
                 FROM
                    Table_khodro 
                 WHERE  
                    active = 0 ";

public DataSet ViewProductKhodro(string name, int firstPrice, int finalPrice, string subCollection, byte state,Int16 model)
{
    if (name !="no name")
        query += @" AND (name_product LIKE '%'+(@name_product)+'%')";

    if (finalPrice != 0)
        query += @" AND (first_price BETWEEN @first_price AND @final_price )";

    if (subCollection !="انتخاب کنید")
        query += @" AND (collection_1 = @collection_1  )";

    if (state != 0)
        query += @" AND (id_state = @id_state  )";

    if(model != 0)
       query += @" AND (model = @model  )";

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query);

    if (name != "no name")
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name_product", name);
    }

    if (finalPrice !=0)
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@first_price", firstPrice);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@final_price", finalPrice);
    }

    if (subCollection != "انتخاب کنید")
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@collection_1", subCollection);

    if (state !=0)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id_state", state);

    if (model != 0)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@model",model );

    // Fill the dataset
    return FillDataSet(cmd, "Table_khodro");
}
```

Now I want to write a stored procedure for this method.

Is it possible with one stored procedure?

How to?

Please help

Comment: It's a **STORED** procedure - as in a procedure that's **STORED** inside your SQL Server - it has nothing to do with a "store" ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can include all those parameters in your query.

```
SELECT  IDproduct ,
        name_product ,
        first_price ,
        final_price ,
        max_registered_price ,
        date_record_shamsi ,
        final_date_view_shamsi ,
        count_views ,
        image_1 ,
        collection_1 ,
        city ,
        model
FROM    Table_khodro
WHERE   active = 0 AND (@NAME IS NULL OR NAME_PRODUCT LIKE @NAME)
AND (@FIRSTPRICE IS NULL OR FIRST_PRICE BETWEEN @FIRSTPRICE AND @FINALPRICE)
```

So your stored procedure would have all the required parameters. You will also have to pass in those parameters which you think might or might not be null. For example if @firstprice  is null your sql query will execute without considering First_price column else it will use the between price and bring the appropriate result set

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for answering
I change the my method like this:

```
 public DataSet ViewProductKhodro(string name, int firstPrice, int finalPrice, string subCollection, byte state,Int16 model)
{  SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.CommandText="search_khodro";
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name_product", name);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@first_price",firstPrice);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@final_price",finalPrice);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@collection_1",subCollection);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id_state", state);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@model", model);
    return FillDataSet(cmd, "Table_khodro");
}
```

And write one stored procedure like this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.search_khodro   
@name_product nvarchar(50),
@first_price  int,
@final_price  int,
@collection_1 nvarchar(30),
@id_state     tinyint ,
@model        smallint
AS begin SELECT IDproduct,name_product,first_price,final_price,max_registered_price,date_record_shamsi,final_date_view_shamsi, count_views,image_1,collection_1,city,model
from 
Table_khodro
 where 
 active=0 And ( @name_product IS NULL OR NAME_PRODUCT LIKE @name_product)  
   And (@first_price IS NULL OR first_price between  @first_price AND @final_price ) 
 And( @collection_1 IS NULL OR collection_1= @collection_1) And(@id_state IS NULL OR id_state=@id_state ) And (@model IS NULL OR model=@model)
end
```

this method have not errors but There is no result .Please check Does there was a problem?